# Command not found! Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-ndk

I am using Linux(Ubuntu 12.04) and i am trying to build the tesseract library. I am using the following command

```
cd <project-directory>/tess-two
export TESSERACT_PATH=${PWD}/external/tesseract-3.01 
export LEPTONICA_PATH=${PWD}/external/leptonica-1.68
export LIBJPEG_PATH=${PWD}/external/libjpeg
ndk-build
android update project --path .
ant release
```

But when I type ndk-build it returns command cannot be found

Please help!

Comment: What is `ndk-build`, and have you installed it?

Comment: ndk-build is the front-end driver of the ndk, which must be installed and either in your path or invoked by the full path of its location.

Comment: try to specify the full path to ndk-build

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html